# Filling in a webform using Arduino and HTTP

Tags: c, http, arduino, webclient

I'm trying to get an arduino to login in to a website that I have created.
On the website there is a basic form that has two fields one for password and one for username, it also has a submit button labelled login.

I used fiddler2 to sniff the http packets when I login in using chrome and am trying to use the information from that http post to recreate my own post to login.

Here is the portion of the code that I am using for the login:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

 Serial.println("connected to server");

// Make a HTTP request:               
 client.println("POST/username=slwhore&passwd=1234qwer%21&op2=login&lang=english&force_session=1&return=B%3AaHR0cDovL3JlbW90bGV0LmNvbS8%3D&message=0&loginfrom=loginmodule&cbsecuritym3=cbm_56b7d5e7_00583e07_b0b6f81b4c86d117542f5cc7b7c3416e&Submit=Login HTTP/1.1");

client.println("Host:www.remotlet.com");

client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

client.println("Content-Length: 229");

client.println("Connection: close");

client.println();
```

I then have another piece of code that recieves the information coming back from the host which I know works. When I run this code I am able to connect to the server but I don't get any response form it at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you aren't sending any form data, the form data would be after your last empty print line, and would look like fieldname=value&otherfieldname=othervalue

Answer (score 2):

Your HTTP request is completely wrong, it will never ever be accepted by any kind of server web.

1st line: the HTTP 1st line is METHOD URI VERSION.
You didn't put a space between the method and the URI, also the POST data is *not* part of the URI as it is when using GET requests. I don't know what your server uses but usually sane logins don't use GET and don't pass the login inside the URI.

2nd line: you forgot a space

4th line: you set a content length but you don't send any content apparently.

General consideration: in HTTP the line terminator is \r\n, not just \n.

I suggest you do the request with the browser, intercept the traffic with wireshark and see how it's done.